# Crash in kevent on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone App in the AppStore which rarely reports crashlogs of a specific type which I cannot reproduce or even find a starting point to look for the problem.

This is the part of the crashlog that is relevant:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  1

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31192974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3123c704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3123c174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3123bb98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311e024a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311d8970 start_wqthread + 0
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem here? I am looking for any hints that allow me to start looking for the problem in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIGSEGV (short for Segmentation Violation) means that your application tries to dereference (access) memory that has not been allocated or can't be dereferenced for other reasons.

The fact that you can't replicate the crash makes it much harder to solve.

All the "_dispatch" calls in your crash log seems to indicate that Thread 1 is using GCD (or maybe some other API that is using GCD behind the scenes) to access some variable that is altered outside the block (from another thread).

It could also be that you are trying to access an uninitialized variable (which is what SIGSEGV usually means).

My recommendation would be to look at any GCD code and other multithreaded code, focusing on thread safety and mutable objects (such as NSMutableArrays).

Also, look over your your memory management and make sure that all variables are initialized and correctly retained/released. I had a crash with a log like yours where the problem was that declared a variable without initializing it right away

```
MyClass *myVariable;
...
// Do some calculations that may or may not initialize the variale
...
if (myVariable) {
    [myVariable doSomething];  // <-- crash
}
```

Changing the declaration to:

```
MyClass *myVariable = nil;
```

Solved my problem.